# Age of empire 3 complete edition: Can we play both expansion at the same time?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

So i installed age of empire 3 complete edition, but when i launch the game, I can either "play Age of empire 3 complete edition", "Age of empire 3 : The war chiefs" or "Age of empire 3 : The asian dynasties".

I was wondering how can I play the content of both expansion at the same time.

Does whatever option i choose, i will get all the content of all the expansion (map, civilization, unit, game mechanic) and its just the campaign of that expansion that wont be available, or do I have to choose a particular launch option like the latest expansion that will also load previous expansion content?

Comment: I don't have the complete edition, but in my experience, launching Asian Dynasties will include Warchiefs content if installed, but *not* vice-versa.  I don't recall how the campaigns worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Age of The Empires 3: The Asian Dynasties includes the The War Chiefs expansion pack.  If you select "Play Asian Dynasties" you will get all DLC.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. You need to upgrade Asian Dynasties AND Warchiefs. Then you can play both at Asian Dynasties. Because AD was relased much later and only after upgrading WC, he can connect with AD.